# Where do I install certificates so that wget and other MacPorts programs will find them?

Tags: macos, wget, macports, ssl-certificate

I have to install custom certificates so that they work with wget installed via MacPorts. I can't find the right directory.

I've tried installing in /System/Library/OpenSSL/certs but that directory seems to be ingored by wget. Likewise certificates installed in my keychain are ignored.

Comment: There is also a `certsync` port which keeps the OpenSSL certificate bundle in sync with your system keychain (by concatenating all your keychain CAs together into`/opt/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem`). If you _only_ care about `wget` working, then `sudo port install certsync; sudo port load certsync` might be the most straightforward solution. I have tested this and it works with a man-in-the-middle root CA installed into the system keychain by my employer. See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `wgetrc` file containing:

```
ca_directory=/System/Library/OpenSSL/certs
```

On Linux and BSD, the file is located at `~/.wgetrc` (and `/etc/wgetrc` system-wide). I don't know if it is the same for MacPorts.

Comment: Very cool. It's `/opt/local/etc/wgetrc` on macports.

Answer (score 9):

The answer above didn't resolve the issue for me, but I found a similar easy solution with MacPorts:

```
sudo port install curl-ca-bundle
```

To install the Certificate Authrity bundle and then push its reference to the wget settings profile:

```
echo CA_CERTIFICATE=/opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt >> ~/.wgetrc
```

Comment: This is a good answer, and it solves a common problem with `wget` and `curl` from MacPorts (getting certificate errors for _every_ SSL/TLS web site). It's just not a solution to what the OP had asked for: a method to install "**custom** certificates" so that `wget` can find them.

Answer (score 3):

(Hello from 2019!) There is now a `certsync` port which keeps the OpenSSL certificates in sync with your system keychain, which can be installed with:

```
sudo port install certsync
```

MacPorts *should* create a launchd startup item to do the sync periodically, but if not, `sudo port load certsync` will do that (use `port unload` to disable it).

This might be useful, if, for example, your Mac is pre-configured by your employer with a local root CA or other man-in-the-middle certs, or you have your own CAs for other reasons. While not impossible, it *would* be a pain to

1. extract those from your system keychain,

   - possibly [converting formats](https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them) with `openssl x509` (ugh),
2. only to dump them somewhere else on your filesystem (that you're guaranteed to forget about in six months),
3. and then, potentially, *also* having to configure every other command-line utility to point to them (as with the `/opt/local/etc/wgetrc` in the other solutions here).

Note that the `certsync` port conflicts with `curl-ca-bundle`, which is in the dependency chain for *many* other MacPorts packages, including `curl`. If you try to proceed, you'll get warnings like this:

```
$ sudo port install certsync

Error: Can't install certsync because conflicting ports are active: curl-ca-bundle
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets to report a bug.
Error: Processing of port certsync failed

$ sudo port uninstall curl-ca-bundle
Note: It is not recommended to uninstall/deactivate a port that has dependents as
it breaks the dependents.
The following ports will break:
 p11-kit @0.23.16.1_0
 neomutt @20180716_0
 neomutt @20180716_1
 curl @7.65.3_1
 subversion @1.12.2_0
Continue? [y/N]:
```

The "broken" ports will *probably* still work regardless, since `certsync` essentially does the job of `curl-ca-bundle` by concatenating all your system keychain's CAs into `/opt/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem`, but I can't certify that.

Still, if you *only* care about getting `wget` working, and are happy with the built-in `/usr/bin/curl` (which is configured to use the macOS system-wide certificate store anyway), simply installing the `certsync` port might be the most straightforward solution.

***Source**: the comments section of [Fixing SSL CA certificates with OpenSSL from MacPorts](https://andatche.com/articles/2012/02/fixing-ssl-ca-certificates-with-openssl-from-macports/) (andatche.com)*

Comment: Pretty neat! Now it's only necessary to update the system keychain!

Answer (score 2):

I can't add a comment to grawity's solution, so I guess I'll create a new answer...

grawity's solution seems to be incomplete.  It worked because you had already "tried installing in /System/Library/OpenSSL/certs".

I installed OpenSSL from MacPorts (newer than the version included with my Snow Leopard install).  This put a `cert.pem` file in `/opt/local/etc/openssl/`, which I could then point to with grawity's method.  This is essentially what I did:

```
sudo port install openssl
sudo echo 'ca_directory = /opt/local/etc/openssl' > /opt/local/etc/wgetrc
sudo cat /opt/local/etc/wgetrc.sample >> /opt/local/etc/wgetrc`
```

Ain's solution probably would have worked for me as well.

Comment: The original post was asking for a method to install "custom certificates." This means the OP had their own `something.pem` file, and they just wanted to put it in a place where `wget` knew (or could be configured) to look for it.